# Unknown provider error while using ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a simple HTTP interceptor in Angular 1.4.x (with ES6 and Babel). The only thing it needs to do is redirect to an error page if a HTTP 500 is detected. The code:

**app/middleware/securityInterceptor.service.js**

```
export default class SecurityInterceptorService {

  constructor($q, $location, config) {
    'ngInject';

    this.$location = $location;
    this.config = config;
    this.$q = $q;
  }

  responseError(rejection) {
    var deferred = this.$q.defer();

    if (rejection.status === 500) {
      this.$location.path(this.config.errorPagePath);
    }

    deferred.reject(rejection);
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

Now I receive an unknown provider error while trying to run the application saying that the `SecurityInterceptorService` is unknown. So I took a look at how it is registered. However, I don't see any obvious errors:

**index.module.js**

```
import interceptorConfig from './index.interceptors';

import SecurityInterceptorService from '../app/middleware/securityInterceptor.service';
// other imports

angular.module('app', ['ngTouch' /*, other dependencies */])
  .config(interceptorConfig)
  .service('securityInterceptorService', SecurityInterceptorService)
  // other declarations
```

**index.interceptors.js**

```
export default function interceptorConfig($httpProvider, securityInterceptorService) {
  'ngInject';

  // Security interceptor
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(securityInterceptorService);
}
```

I can enter the `interceptorConfig` function when removing the `securityInterceptorService` dependency. So it seems the service is not registered. Checked all file paths, checked for spelling errors in the variable names, et cetera.

I'd appreciate if someone is able to point out the mistake I made.

------------------------ Update

The following function that is injected via `.config()` does work however. Yet, when I try to push the securityInterceptor in this function, I get the same unknown provider error.

```
export default function config($logProvider, $locationProvider, toastr, $compileProvider) {
  'ngInject';

  // Enable log
  $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);

  // Set options third-party lib
  toastr.options.timeOut = 3000;
  toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-top-right';
  toastr.options.preventDuplicates = true;
  toastr.options.progressBar = true;

  // HTML 5 Modus Enabled No #
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false,
    hashPrefix: '!'
  });

  // Disable debug info
  $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: `function interceptorConfig($httpProvider, securityInterceptorService)`  -> `securityInterceptorService` is not a provider, is it?

Comment: @zeroflagL It is not a provider.

Comment: That's what I said and that's the problem. You can only inject providers into a config function.

Comment: I updated my post with some example code that does work and is also not a provider. It's run by using `.config(config)`. That one fails too whenever I try to add the securityInterceptor to it. So there is something wrong with that class.

Comment: What is the exact error? I doubt that `toastr` is registered as a service.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @zeroflagL! It made me realize the mistake I made.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out dat you cannot inject services in the `.config()`. It all works fine when changing `index.interceptors.js` to this:

```
export default function interceptorConfig($httpProvider) {
  'ngInject';

  // Security interceptor
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('securityInterceptorService');
}
```